# Cannot create a pop up from a grid view using Popupcontrolextender

Tags: c#, web-services, datagridview, popupcontrolextender

I am trying to create a gridview with an icon that when hovered over shows some more details. I have managed to get it to the point of showing the panel but it keeps showing the html that is loaded as the page is loaded.

Here is the html.

```
<%@ Page Title="HueniData" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="HueniData.aspx.cs" Inherits="Dateflowe.HueniData" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>


<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <br />
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblToDate" runat="server" Text="To Date" Width="150px"></asp:Label>
        <asp:Label ID="lblFromDate" runat="server" Text="From Date" Width="150px"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtToDate" runat="server" type="date" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" runat="server" type="date" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Label ID="txtIncorrectDateError" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Red" Visible="false"></asp:Label><br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnSelectDate" runat="server" Text="Select" OnClick="btnSelectDate_Click" />
        <br />
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div style="width: 1050px; height: 300px; overflow: auto; margin-left: 40px">
        <asp:GridView ID="HueniGrid" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="Black" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Silver" RowStyle-BackColor="#EEEEEE" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="White"
            AlternatingRowStyle-ForeColor="#000" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="true" Visible="false" OnRowCreated="HueniGrid_RowCreated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LotNo" HeaderText="Lot No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Recipe" HeaderText="Recipe" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PlantOrigin" HeaderText="Plant Origin" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LoadWeight" HeaderText="Load Weight" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartTime" HeaderText="Start Time" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="StartedBy" HeaderText="Started By" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="BatchNo" HeaderText="Batch No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DrumNo" HeaderText="Drum No" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalActualDuration" HeaderText="Total Actual Duration" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TotalRecipeDuration" HeaderText="Total Recipe Duration" />

                <%--Adding javascript field for pop up--%>
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="http://sheepsystems.com/bookmacster/HelpBook/images/InlineMagGlass.png" />
                        <ajax:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server"
                            PopupControlID="Panel1" 
                            TargetControlID="Image1"  
                            DynamicContextKey='<%# Eval("BatchNo") %>'  
                            DynamicControlID="Panel1"  
                            DynamicServiceMethod="GetContent" Position="Bottom">  
                        </ajax:PopupControlExtender>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server"></asp:Panel> <%--This is the popup--%>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

**and the relevant code:**

```
protected void HueniGrid_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        PopupControlExtender pce = e.Row.FindControl("PopupControlExtender1") as PopupControlExtender;
        string behaviourID = "pce_" + e.Row.RowIndex;
        pce.BehaviorID = behaviourID;

        Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("Image1");

        string OnMouseOverScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').showPopup();", behaviourID);
        string OnMouseOutScript = string.Format("$find('{0}').hidePopup();", behaviourID);

        img.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", OnMouseOverScript);
        img.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", OnMouseOutScript);
    }
}

[System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string GetDynamicContent(string contextKey)  //static method
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dataflowe_dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 OperationName FROM DrumProcess WHERE BatchNo = " + contextKey;

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connectionString);
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(table);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    builder.Append("<table style='background-color:#f3f3f3; border: #336699 3px solid; ");
    builder.Append("width: 350px; font-size:10pt; font-family:Verdana; ' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>");
    builder.Append("<tr><td colspan='3' style='background-color:#336699; color:white;'>");
    builder.Append("<tr><td style='width:80px;'><b>OperationName</b></td>");
    builder.Append("<tr>");
    builder.Append("<td>" + table.Rows[0]["OperationName"].ToString() + "</td>");
    builder.Append("</tr>");
    builder.Append("</table>");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

What happens is it shows everything on the page as it first loads into the panel. From what I can personally see the problem is that it never calls the second method GetDynamicContent. It runs through the first method fine though. I have read this may to be to do with a web services file been called, rather than the method, which results in the page been reloaded? I have no clue about this. I added this:

```
DynamicServicePath="HueniData.aspx.cs"
```

When I do this the pop up no longer shows but neither does the data. Nothing shows.

When I use:

```
DynamicServicePath="HueniData.aspx"
```

I get an error message showing in the pop up panel which states: Web Service Call Failed: 200

I am completely lost and hope someone can help

Comment: GridView != DataGridView !

Comment: Sorry did this late at night. Corrected.

Comment: And now for the Tags..!

Comment: Maybe you could suggest what is wrong, because it is pretty unhelpful otherwise.

Comment: No I can't, I don't do ASP, sorry! But as you still have no set the right Tags, you are still not getting the attention of those who do. I think this hint is rather helpful..